# How/Where can I get a list of all resource names in DbPedia?

Tags: python, sparql, rdf, dbpedia

I am trying to build a question answering system that retrieves answer from DbPedia. At a certain step, I need to find the appropriate resource name to perform the query operation. For that, I was planning to store all the resource name in a database and retrieve the most relavant ones.

Now I'm stuck at this step. I'm new to this whole DbPedia thing and I'm not actually sure if there is a way to get all the resource list of DbPedia.

Previously, I had used python's [wikipedia library](https://pypi.org/project/wikipedia/) to get the resource name. But it does not return any value for certain test cases. And so I need to change my approach.

Comment: Can you please add an example of the code you are using and be a bit more specific about what it is you're doing?

Comment: @ValerioCocchi, in short I just need a list of all the existing resource names (english) in DBpedia. I want to know if there is a code to retrieve this list or if it exists as a dataset.

Comment: I'll be editing my question to make it more clear.

Comment: And your issue is with writing the SPARQL query or the python code?

Comment: write a SPARQL query or just parse the N-Triples dump via command line or Python - both are trivial

Comment: you should also check why your wikipedia library doesn't return anything - which cases exactly? What is your input and what your expected output? What is the use case at all?

Comment: You need to get accustomed first to the concept of RDF graphs and how to query them with SPARQL. Then you need to understand the structure of DBPedia. Once you do that, the answers will come to you in the best case, or you will be able to have more concrete questions in the worst case. Either way, it will move you forward.